# Is there wildcard for annotatted classes

Tags: java, annotations

Persistent object:

```
@Entity
public class PersistentModelObject{
  ...
}
```

I need something like:

```
interface GenericDao<T annotated_with Entity>{
  //crud
}
```

Or can it be simulated in some way (with extension, implementation, etc).

EDIT: Please someone who understands my question to edit it to some understandable level.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can use annotations like that via generics, but you can use java.lang.Class java.lang.reflect.Field isAnnotationPresent(YourAnnotation.class) to check if a class is annotated with a certain annotation.

A better aproach might be using marker interfaces? Something like:

```
public class PersistentModelObject implements MyPersistableType{
     ...
}
```

and

```
interface MyPersistableType {} //marker interface
```

Then you may use it like this:

```
interface GenericDao<T extends MyPersistableType>{
  //crud
}
```

But then again, it depends on what you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This restriction can only be checked at runtime using reflection.